# MySQL Query Building and geo points

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Table called ads , each ad has a unique `id` and geo point field called `location` ,

What I am doing now is counting how many ads near a certain point `POINT(46.52167 23.81167)` and it works fine using this SQL Query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    MAX(ST_DISTANCE(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(46.52167 23.81167)'),
            location)) AS radius
FROM
    ads
WHERE
    ST_DISTANCE(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(46.52167 23.81167)'),
            location) < 0.17536759746391475;
```

Sometimes I have 20 points or more on a request and I want to run this query for all of them , It takes a lot of time because I use multiple queries combined together.

for example I have two points `POINT(46.52167 23.81167)` and `POINT(46.72417 23.51167)` I use the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    MAX(ST_DISTANCE(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(46.52167 23.81167)'),
            location)) AS radius
FROM
    ads
WHERE
    ST_DISTANCE(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(46.52167 23.81167)'),
            location) < 0.17536759746391475;
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    MAX(ST_DISTANCE(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(46.72417 23.51167)'),
            location)) AS radius
FROM
    ads
WHERE
    ST_DISTANCE(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(46.72417 23.51167)'),
            location) < 0.17536759746391475;
```

My Question : Is there any way to optimize and combine these two queries into one ? using grouping or having or any method or algorithm ?

Comment: You could obviously use union to combine the 2 queries into one. I fail to see any other optimization, since you want records that are within a certain radius of 2 distinct points.